# Laplacian opencv fails with cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I am trying to apply laplacian to a median filter output to get a sharper image, by later processing. The code snippet is as below :

```
img = plt.imread('example.png')
img_res = cv.resize(img,(256,256))
gray_image = cv.cvtColor(img_res, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
median_img = median_filter(gray_image, 5)
# Calculate the Laplacian
lap_img = cv.Laplacian(median_img,cv.CV_64F)
```

The input image is a RGB medical image. I am faced with the following error, when running this code:

```
 cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:/projects/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/filter.simd.hpp:3175: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Unsupported combination of source format (=5), and destination format (=6) in function 'cv::opt_AVX2::getLinearFilter'
```

This error occurs for any image from the dataset. Could you please point out what could be the issue? The example is followed from this [link](https://www.idtools.com.au/unsharp-masking-python-opencv/) for grayscale images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two different libraries (`matplotlib` and `opencv`), stick to using one library at a time while performing image-processing. The reason is because these two libraries use different formats to store images. `matplotlib` uses `RGB` convention while `opencv` uses `BGR`. My guess is that you're encountering this error due to using `matplotlib` to load the image, and then performing operations with `opencv`. Simply, loading the image using `cv2.imread()` instead of `plt.imread()` seems to fix the problem

Input `->` Output

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
from scipy.ndimage.filters import median_filter
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
median_img = median_filter(gray_image, 5)
# Calculate the Laplacian
lap_img = cv2.Laplacian(median_img,cv2.CV_64F).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('lap_img', lap_img)
cv2.imwrite('lap_img.png', lap_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: just to add on to that, I find the result not exactly as shown in the link. I find it rather inverted or a loosely subracted image. What could be the issue?

Comment: I'm unable to obtain the same results using their code as well. Maybe you should try looking at a different tutorial